# ifstream does not work in loop

Tags: c++

I just started programming using C++. I face some problem during execution of ifstream in loop.

```
do  
{  
    system("cls");  
    inFile.open ("Account_Details.txt");  
    while (!inFile.eof())  
    {  
         getline (inFile, line);  
         cout << line << endl;  
    }  
         inFile.close();  
         cin.ignore(100, '\n');  
         cin >> choice;  
}  
while (choice != '1' && choice != '2');
```

This is part of my code. When the loop run, it doesnt show data in the txt file.
Thanks for any help. ^^

Comment: Works for me with a few assumptions about the code you didn't show, which means my assumptions are wrong.  Please provide a complete self-contained test case that can be compiled.

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to do `while (!file.eof())` in C++. Try `while (getline(...)) {}`.

Comment: So, it doesn't print anything at all?

Comment: It does print out everything inside my file. Just doesnt work in the do..while loop.

Answer (score 3):

add infile.clear() after the infile.close() - the eof bits are not cleared by the close

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that the file doesn't exist. If that's the case, it will create an empty file. Check the path of the file.

Comment: The OP could be using the global `getline` that's in `<string>`.

Comment: @Zach, ah, yes... that would change things.

Comment: Erm.. My file does execute for the first time. But when choice is not equal to 1 & 2, the file cannot open.  If I use   inFile.getline(line, limit);  does that means that I will have to calculate the number of characters in my file?

Comment: @CN L, no. It will stop at `\n` or the end of the file. But as Zach pointed out, there may be something wrong with `line`. What type is it?

Comment: @CN L: Then maybe your file is empty, or maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: My file have data, and the path is correct. Wonder why it will skip the file part when loop for the 2nd time...

Comment: I think I will just loop for the choice part. Anyway thanks for helping. ^^

Comment: It works now. After inFile.close(), I should add inFIle.clear() to reset the content inside my file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been writing C++ code for close to 10 years. During that time I have learnt how to use C++ in a way that minimizes the number of errors (bugs) I create. Probably some will disagree with me, but I would recommend you to only use for and while to do looping. Never do-while. Learn these two well and you will be able to loop successfully any time you want.

To illustrate my technique, I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code using my style. It has complete error checking, uses a while loop with read-ahead, some C++0x, and simplified stream handling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   // check program arguments
   if (argc<2) {
      std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " file" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   // check file can be opened
   std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
   if (!infile) {
      std::cerr << "Failed to read " << argv[1] << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   std::string input;

   // read-ahead
   std::getline(std::cin, input);

   while (input!="q" && input!="quit" && input!="exit") {
      //system("cls");

      // print contents of file by streaming its read buffer
      std::cout << infile.rdbuf();

      // read file again
      infile = std::ifstream(argv[1]);

      // finally, read again to match read-ahead
      std::getline(std::cin, input);
   }
}
```

Save to **main.cpp**, compile to **print.exe** and run with **print.exe main.cpp**.
Good luck with learning C++!